# Avoid duplicate call in LaunchEffect with multiple key in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to avoid multiple function call when `LaunchEffect` key triggers.

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = isEnableState, key2 = viewModel.uiState) {
     viewModel.scanState(bluetoothAdapter)
}
```

when first composition `isEnableState` and `viewModel.uiState` both will trigger twice and call `viewModel.scanState(bluetoothAdapter)`.

`isEnableState` is a `Boolean` type and `viewModel.uiState` is sealed class of UI types.

```
var uiState by mutableStateOf<UIState>(UIState.Initial)
        private set 
var isEnableState by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set
```

So how can we handle idiomatic way to avoid duplicate calls?

Thanks

UPDATE

**ContentStateful**

```
@Composable
fun ContentStateful(
    context: Context = LocalContext.current,
    viewModel: ContentViewModel = koinViewModel(),
) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = viewModel.isEnableState, key2 = viewModel.uiState) {
        viewModel.scanState(bluetoothAdapter)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(viewModel.previous) {
        viewModel.changeDeviceSate()
    }
    ContentStateLess{
        viewModel.isEnableState = false
    }
}
```

**ContentStateLess**

```
@Composable
fun ContentStateLess(changeAction: () -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = { changeAction() }) {
        Text(text = "Click On me")
    }
}
```

**ContentViewModel**

```
class ContentViewModel : BaseViewModel() {
    var uiState by mutableStateOf<UIState>(UIState.Initial)
    var isEnableState by mutableStateOf(false)
    
    fun scanState(bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter) {
        if (isEnableState && isInitialOrScanningUiState()) {
            // start scanning
        } else {
            // stop scanning
        }
    }

    private fun isInitialOrScanningUiState(): Boolean {
        return (uiState == UIState.Initial || uiState == UIState.ScanningDevice)
    }

    fun changeDeviceSate() {
        if (previous == BOND_NONE && newState == BONDING) {
            uiState = UIState.LoadingState
        } else if (previous == BONDING && newState == BONDED) {
            uiState = UIState.ConnectedState(it)
        } else {
            uiState = UIState.ConnectionFailedState
        }
    }
}
```

`scanState` function is start and stop scanning of devices.

Comment: Add an if condition inside the block.

Comment: what should be check inside if block?

Comment: You are using 2 keys and it works as intended. What do you want to avoid? Are there some states or combinations where the viewModel.scanState shouldn't be called?

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti `isEnableState` is changing in some condition and i want to trigger `scanState`.  `uiState` is changing continuous and also want to trigger function. My main problem is when 1st composition happens I don't want to call twice `scanState` function.  I used both keys because whenever variable value changes I want to trigger `scanState` but only once. If you don't understand please ask me, I'll add more code in my example

Comment: It seems like both keys depend on each other. Are they changing separately?

Comment: @Steyrix yes they are changing separately..

Comment: What does `scanState` do?

Comment: It's just a function to start and scan in background. I added my code

Comment: Can you post the full code of composable function in which you call launched effect?

Comment: Full code will be not possible instead I'll add revalent code.

Comment: @Steyrix I added all code which is using `isEnableState` and `uiState`..

Comment: Don't know if it's related, but it looks impossible for this condition to ever be true. `previous == BOND_NONE && previous == BONDING` Same with the else-if condition.

Comment: @Tenfour04 good catch, I was forgot to change the variable. Now it fixed, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer below would work or might require some modification to work but logic for preventing double clicks can be used only if you wish to prevent actions happen initially within time frame of small interval. To prevent double clicks you you set current time and check again if the time is above threshold to invoke click callback. In your situation also adding states with delay might solve the issue.

```
IDLE, BUSY, READY


var launchState by remember {mutableStateOf(IDLE)}
LaunchedEffect(key1 = isEnableState, key2 = viewModel.uiState) {
     if(launchState != BUSY){
          viewModel.scanState(bluetoothAdapter)
          if(launchState == IDLE){ launchState = BUSY)
     }
}



LaunchedEffect(launchState) {
     if(launchState == BUSY){
           delay(50)
           launchState = READY
     }
}
```

Comment: Is it able to call launched effect with `scanState` second time? It should come from READY to BUSY

Comment: launchState goes into IDLE, BUSY only on first composition and changes to READY after 50ms or specific delay. ON READY state after that launched works as in question. It only acts sa temporary blocker for specific time

Comment: @Thracian perfect it works as expected. Thanks